# How do I remove sphinx_deleted from a Sphinx query?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, thinking-sphinx

I am new to Ruby and ThinkingSphinx. 
I have the following Sphinx Query -  SELECT * FROM `user_core`, `user_delta` WHERE `sphinx_deleted` = 0.

I do not want to see the condition "WHERE 'sphinx_deleted' = 0. How do I remove this? I have removed the sql_attr_uint = sphinx_deleted from my sphinx.conf file, yet I see the sphinx_deleted being passed in the query.

Here is the index file definition:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :user, :with => :active_record, :delta => true do
  indexes [first_name,last_name,display_name], :as=>:name, :sortable=>true
  indexes first_name,     :sortable => true
  indexes last_name,      :sortable => true
  indexes display_name,   :sortable => true
  indexes email,          :sortable => true
  indexes phone,          :sortable => true
  indexes title,          :sortable => true

  has id,          :as => :user_id
  has roles(:id),         :as => :role_ids
  has jurisdictions(:id), :as => :jurisdiction_ids

  set_property :delta =>  true
end
```

I do not have a sphinx_scope or default_sphinx_scope defined.

We are using thinking-sphinx-3.1.0 and ruby-2.1.0

Answer (score 2):

The `sphinx_deleted` attribute is created by Thinking Sphinx, and is used in the following cases (using your scenario of a User model with core and delta indices in the examples):

- When a User is deleted, `sphinx_deleted` is set to 1 for that record in both the core and delta indices - there's no point returning Sphinx records if the underlying ActiveRecord object no longer exists.
- When a User is updated, the delta index is processed with the latest field and attribute details, and the core index's document has sphinx_deleted set to 1, so only the latest (accurate) information will match. e.g. if a user has their name changed from Fred to Georgina, a search for 'Fred' will not return Georgina, because the core index document (which *does* match) is filtered out.

That is why the attribute exists. You cannot tell Thinking Sphinx to not add it, nor can you remove that filter, short of mucking around in the internals of Thinking Sphinx.

If there is a specific reason for wanting to remove the attribute and filter, feel free to comment here, or you can open an issue on [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/), or post to the [TS Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/thinking-sphinx).

**Update**

Okay, further to this, there are three ways around it.

**Option One:**

The first way is to make the query to Sphinx yourself, using a Thinking Sphinx connection:

```
results = ThinkingSphinx::Connection.take do |connection|
  connection.execute "SELECT * FROM user_core, user_delta"
end
```

Keep in mind that this returns raw Sphinx values, *not* ActiveRecord instances.

**Option Two:**

A more complicated alternative, though, is to have your own search middleware stack. First, you'll want to create a custom subclass of `ThinkingSphinx::Middlewares::SphinxQL` that removes the `:sphinx_deleted` filter:

```
class SphinxQLWithoutFilter < ThinkingSphinx::Middlewares::SphinxQL
  def call(contexts)
    contexts.each do |context|
      Inner.new(context).call
    end

    app.call contexts
  end

  private

  class Inner < ThinkingSphinx::Middlewares::SphinxQL::Inner
    def inclusive_filters
      super.except :sphinx_deleted
    end
  end
end
```

Then, create a new middleware stack which uses this new SphinxQL query middleware:

```
WithoutFilterMiddleware = ::Middleware::Builder.new do
  use ThinkingSphinx::Middlewares::StaleIdFilter
  use SphinxQLWithoutFilter
  use ThinkingSphinx::Middlewares::Geographer
  use ThinkingSphinx::Middlewares::Inquirer
  use ThinkingSphinx::Middlewares::ActiveRecordTranslator
  use ThinkingSphinx::Middlewares::StaleIdChecker
  use ThinkingSphinx::Middlewares::Glazier
end
```

And then you can use that middleware stack in specific search queries:

```
User.search 'foo', :middleware => WithoutFilterMiddleware
```

It's worth noting the two middleware present in that stack for stale ids. They work together to catch any Sphinx results that do not have a matching ActiveRecord object, and re-run the Sphinx query up to three times filtering out those unmatched records. They're probably useful, but if you don't want to use them, you can remove them from your custom stack. However, without them, any Sphinx records that don't have matching ActiveRecord objects will be transformed into nils.

**Option Three:**

This is the more hackish version of the previous solution, but will apply to *all* searches, so probably isn't worthwhile: re-open the class that adds the filter with `class_eval` and change the method definition:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Middlewares::SphinxQL::Inner.class_eval do
  def inclusive_filters
    # normally:
    # (options[:with] || {}).merge({:sphinx_deleted => false})
    # but without the sphinx_deleted filter:
    options[:with] || {}
  end
end
```

Now, all that said: I presume you're not actually deleting users, but somehow the deletion callbacks are being fired anyway? Hence, users *do* exist but are currently being filtered out by Sphinx? If so, I highly recommend not using ActiveRecord's `destroy` method, and instead having a custom method to mark users as inactive. This avoids the callbacks, and thus avoids the need for any of the above 'solutions'.

Comment: Pat,Thanks for your quick reply. I need to be able to retrieve the deleted records for a certain condition and retrieve all the records(both marked deleted and not deleted) for another condition. How do I modify the query, so that I can pass in sphinx_deleted = 1 sometimes and ignore the sphinx_deleted condition at other times?

Comment: Added further detail, but just to be clear: if you need to do this, it feels like something in your implementation is unwise, and I would recommend finding a different way to approach the feature instead of using any of the solutions I've suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solutions.I am not using destroy to remove the record. There is a deleted_at column in the user table that is set if we delete the user. I am not sure why sphinx is not retrieving the records that have deleted_at set.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be the case. If you'd like to update the question with the index definition and the versions of Thinking Sphinx and Sphinx that you're using, that might provide some clues. Also: do you have any Sphinx scopes on your model (in particular, a default scope)?

Comment: I have updated the question with the index definition.

Comment: I can't see anything there that would stop results from appearing when you're changing your own deleted_at column. Are delta results working generally, outside of this specific situation?